# Apply constraint if conditions match

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I have a Symfony form. In this form, I have two fields:

"House number" and "Po Box". They're defined like this:

```
$builder->add('houseNumber', TextType::class, [
    'label' => 'Huisnummer',
    'attr' => [
        'maxlength' => 8,
    ],
    'constraints' => [
        new NotBlank([
            'groups' => $options['constraint_groups']
        ]),
        new Regex([
            'pattern' => '/^[0-9]+$/',
            'message' => 'Vul alleen het huisnummer in cijfers in.'
        ]),
        new Length([
            'groups' => $options['constraint_groups'],
            'max' => 8
        ])
    ]
])->add('poBox', TextType::class, [
    'label' => 'Postbus',
    'attr' => [
        'maxlength' => 10,
    ],
    'constraints' => [
        new Length([
            'groups' => $options['constraint_groups'],
            'max' => 10
        ])
    ]
]);
```

Is there a way for me to make it so that the Housenumber not required if the PoBox is present and vice versa?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds more a job for client-side than server-side

Comment: @treyBake The form is rendered through Formbuilder, and I have to validate everything's like I want it to be, no?

Comment: You can't pick up on client-side through server-side without sending the information first. The best thing you can do is make both required then in client-side (using JS) create an eventHandler that uses if statements to remove required attribute from the input field if one is filled out

Comment: @treyBake You're telling me not to validate on the server side of things? Seems like an odd solution?

Comment: Not what I said at all, I said remove the required attribute via client side. You can still validate PHP side, just via the form action - not from the form builder

Comment: You can use a [Callback-constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html). If I am not mistaken the `$object` being validated is your form, so you can just get the data from each field and check it using e.g. a static callback. If this does not work you can create a method on the object being validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom validation constraint

```
namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target({"CLASS", "ANNOTATION"})
 */
class HouseNumber extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Some message';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

Validator

```
namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class HouseNumberValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($obj, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof HouseNUmber) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, __NAMESPACE__ . '\HouseNUmber');
        }

        $error = null;

        if (!$this->isValid($obj)) {
            $error = $constraint->message;
        }

        if (!empty($error)) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($error)
                ->atPath('houseNumber')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }

    private function isValid($obj)
    {    
        if (!$obj instanceof SomeClass) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($obj, SomeClass::class);
        }

        if (!empty($obj->getPoBox())) {
            return true;
        }

        return !empty($obj->getHouseNumber());
    }
}
```

And to your field $houseNumber in class add annotation

```
use App\Validator\Constraints as AppAssert;

/**
 * @AppAssert\HouseNumber
 */
class SomeClass 
{
    private $houseNumber;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is on the right path but I think it should be a class validator not a property validator. Since it requires 2 exact properties of that class in order to be able to validate, it actually validates the integrity of the class in regards to the two properties. This will also allow him to use the validator inside the form

Comment: Yes, you right. I updated answer but didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to make what you want is to create a custom class constraint validator (https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator).

I don't know if you can add this constraint on form or if you have to relate your form to an entity.